# OOP object creation guidelines

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Suppose to have a polygon class like this one:

```
public class Polygon 
{
   Point[] _vertices;

   public class Polygon(Point[] vertices)
   {
       _vertices = vertices;
   }
}
```

To make triangles, squares, hexagons would you rather:

- Inherit from Polygon your Triangle, Square, etc. class that provides a
  specific constructor and generate points programmatically?
- Add a `CreateSquare` static method that returns a ready to use Polygon class?

This:

```
public class Square : Polygon
{
   public class Polygon(double size)
   {
       _vertices = new Point[]{ new Point(0,0), new Point(size,0), new Point(size,size), new Point(0,size)};
   }
}
```

or this:

```
public class Polygon 
{
    Point[] _vertices;

    public class Polygon(Point[] vertices)
    {
       _vertices = vertices;
    }

    public static Polygon CreateSquare(double size)
    {
        double verts = new Point[]{ new Point(0,0), new Point(size,0), new Point(size,size), new Point(0,size)};

        return new Polygon(verts);
    }  
 }
```

What approach is more correct from the OOP programming point of view? Please note that there derived classes don't add anything to original Polygon one.

In addition, in the latter case, is there any convenient naming convention?

Is there any additional approach I don't know about?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there for real world programming, or some kind of test (my answer would differ between them)?

Comment: +1 for second approach because of the ``Please note that their derived classes don't add anything to original Polygon one.``

Comment: I don't know C# specifically but this is interesting because my first thought was overloading the constructor, which is the behavior I think you want ideally, but unlike traditional constructor overloading, the choice of parameters isn't a good indicator of what type is being instantiated.

Comment: In the real world, `Polygon` might be an interface instead since particular more specialized polygons allow for a lot different implementations that may make a base implementation too generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's never a definite answer for this question without knowing the context in which these classes are being used, however if there's no need for more specific classes I wouldn't create them. You wouldn't create a `RedPolygon` or `BlueSquare` either, should you add a `Color` property to `Polygon`.

As soon as there is behavior exclusive to squares you could create the child class - I could for instance imagine that some mathematical operations like a hit test would perform faster on squares than on polygons-that-happen-to-be-squares.

Answer (score 2):

To adhear to the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles. I would go with the solution using inheritance.

The [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) states entities should be open for extension, but closed for modification. So to get another shape you shouldn't need to touch the Polygon class.

If someone wants to add a Hexagon he would simply create a new source file with the Hexagon inherit from Polygon instead of modifying your existing Polygon source which would require him to have access to your source. Also modifying existing source code would add the risk of introducing bugs with your new code. While for your simple example the risk wouldn't be that big for just creating new shapes, the risk would rise as soon as you want to add some calculations specific to the different shapes.

You could argue with the [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle which states you should not implement some feature if there is no need to. So if you don't need to account for further extension cause you got full control over your source and all the programms that use this source you could also go with the other solution using static "factory" methods.

For a more in depth discussion you could refer to [this article](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/11/28/ocp-vs-yagni/)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to add specific classes for Square, Triangle, etc. if they don't extend Polygon.

Your statment that they derived classes don't add anything to Polygon could indicate a "HAS A" rather than "IS A" relationship.
A Square IS A Polygon, but it HAS vertices.

That said, I wouldn't put them as static methods in the class either, unless you intend to cater for only a fixed number of polygon types. Since there an infinite number of polygons, will you edit the class when you need to add a new shape?

If a Polygon is an elementary object, it should be left as a simple elementary object, and leave it to a factory to create specific.

Again, that said, this sounds more like an exam question that is a bit ambiguous & is intentionally at that point where things get blurry.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean exactly with _and leave it to a factory to create specific_? An additional class that create objects?

Comment: Yes a factory is a additional class wichs sole purpose is to create some kind of objects. It's used to encapsulate the knowledge how an object has to be created.